# Xcode Work Space Integrity Error when trying to run program copied from another Mac

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

My buddy sent me his xcode project. First, we tried zipping and downloading from dropbox. Then we tried copying with a flash drive. When I run the program, I get "Workspace Integrity" "Could not load project pods.xcodeproj" and "Could not load project `projectname`.xcodeproj".

Things I've tried:

I deleted Podfile.lock and Podfile and the .xcworkspace. I then ran pod install, and recreated those files. Xcode was closed. No luck.

I check the project.pbxproj file for any errors but I couldn't find anything. (Note: other than <<< , >>> , === I don't know what to look for)

Has anybody else ran into this issue?

Comment: Ask your buddy to make sure he didn't add the projects with an absolute path (which can happen unintentionally). When opening the workspace (obviously on the computer where the workspace builds), select each project and check in the right Utilities pane (on the right side), in the "File Inspector" tab, that the "Location" is not set to "Absolute Path".

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Project file inspector location is set to "Relative to Group". There's also relative to workspace and relative to developer directory.

Comment: Ok, my next try would be to individually open each project (`.xcodeproj`) on your computer and see if it builds.

Comment: Yes, all other projects build.

Comment: Huh, then I'm out of ideas, sorry :) If you can't find a proper solution you could just recreate the workspace on your computer.. should hopefully not be too hard :)

Comment: Thanks for the help. I was able to start a new project, copy the files over to it, install the pods, and it worked.

Comment: I found out that the other user had a different version of xcode. I had 9.1. He had 9.4. For some reason, it didnt say i had an update available. I had to go into the app store and redownload xcode. Once I did that everything worked smoothly.